# sliding an image with different intervals using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, jquery-animate

I have an image that is very long and needs to be moved from left to right within the HTML #container I've created.

The image contains around 4 paintings and the slider needs to use a comfortable speed and stop for a few seconds when one of the painintgs is in the middle. then continues to the next painting within the image.

It should start on a button click and begin and end on the first painting which is visible

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="img" src="panorama.png"/>
</div>
<div id="start">
    <h2 class="text">Start</h2>
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#start').click(function()        
    {           
        var change_img_time     = 5000; 
        var transition_speed    = 100;      
        $('#container img');
        {

        }           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1mw6m0eh/7/):

---

javascript/ jQuery:

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // My controls (in miliseconds)
    var change_img_time  = 1000;
    var transition_speed = 1000;

    // Image properties
    var image = $("div#container > img.img");
    var aQuarter = image.width() / 4;
    var copyIMG = image.clone();
    image.after( copyIMG );
    copyIMG.css({
        "margin-top": 0 - image.innerHeight(),
        "margin-left": copyIMG.width()
    });
    image = image.add(copyIMG);
    var relative = $("<div>").css({
        "position": "relative",
        "padding": "0"
    });
    $("div#container").wrapInner(relative);

    // Setting container-div width and height
    $("div#container").css({
        "width": aQuarter,
        "height": image.height()
    });

    // Start-event
    $("div#start").on("click", function startImageEvent() {
        if (image.is(":animated")) return;
        image
            .animate({
                "margin-left": "-=" + aQuarter
            }, transition_speed)
            .delay(change_img_time)
            .animate({
                "margin-left": "-=" + aQuarter
            }, transition_speed)
            .delay(change_img_time)
            .animate({
                "margin-left": "-=" + aQuarter
            }, transition_speed)
            .delay(change_img_time)
            .animate({
                "margin-left": "-=" + aQuarter
            }, transition_speed, function(){
                image.not(copyIMG).css("margin-left", "0");
                copyIMG.css({"margin-left": copyIMG.width()});
                $("div#start").one("click", startImageEvent);
            });
    });

});
```

---

and the css is also important:

---

```
div#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
div#start {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 30px;
    border: 1px dotted #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div#container img.img {
    float: left;
}
```

---

I tried to do the code legible, but if you have any doubts, let me know..

Hope it helps.